# UIView sidebar always on top

Tags: ios, layout, uiview, uiviewcontroller, sidebar

I'm developing an iPad application and I need to create an `UIView` that is always on top in respect to other views.

A is the area (consider it as a sort of sidebar) where I need to create a `UIViewController` which view remains always on top. B, instead, is the content area where a `UIViewController` (with its view) can change: depending on several button actions (inside A's view), it's possible to remove the current visible content (in this case controller B and its view) and display other controllers (C, D, E, etc.) with theirs views.

I created all the elements for my application but I have problems to maintain A's view on top and, at the same time, implement the logic used to dinamcally change the content area. As requirements I need that A always overlaps B. In other words, a portion of B (the left part) is always under the area of A. B always extends the entire device screen.

Could you give me some advice?

I made two configurations but I have problem with them.

**First Configuration**

In the first one, I created an `UIViewController` for A (called `SideBarController`). I added `SideBarController` view to `UIWindow` (within the application delegate). Then I created an `UIViewController` for B (called `HomeViewController`) and I added it as a `rootViewController` for my application.

This solution could be a valid one because I can change the content area dinamically (setting a new `rootViewController`) through my application delegate but the `SideBarController` remains always under the current visble view.

**Second Configuration**

In the second one, I created an `UIViewController` (called `MainViewController`) and I added it as a `rootViewController` for my application. Then within `MainViewController` I created an `UIViewController` for A (called `SideBarController`) and I added `SideBarController` view to `MainViewController`. Then the content area has been filled creating an `UIViewController` for B (called `HomeViewController`) and adding it to `MainViewController`.

The sidebar remains always on top but I have difficulties to change dynamically the content area within `MainViewController`. How is it possible to access the content area and change it?

**Note** I'm aware about standard components on UIKit but I need to implements such a solution because of user specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would begin by trying to implement your sidebar in a `UIPopoverController`. It's designed pretty well for this kind of problem, and you can customize it extensively to meet your UI needs. If `UIPopoverController` causes you some kind of problem, I'd put the sidebar in its own `UIWindow` and float that over the main window.

**EDIT**

Personally I'd go for the popover myself since it's more built for this kind of issue. Another thought that comes to mind and I've used in the past is a `UIView` that you add to directly to the `UIWindow` (`[view window]` from any view will get you the main one). Remember, `UIWindow` is just a special kind of `UIView`. The problem with this and the `UIWindow` solution is that you will have to do your own rotation logic which can be trickier than it sounds if you have autorotations. `UIPopoverController` handles all this very cleanly and automatically if you can use it.

If you pursue `UIWindow` see the Windows section of the View Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you give me advices for the second solution? How is it possible to put the sidebar inside another `UIWindow`? I think the first one could be complex. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know about the way to follow. Maybe `UIPopoverController` could be the right one. The problem, in my opinion, could be the impossibility to customize the appearance of this controller. For example, in iOS 4, it's not possible to customize the border. I don't know if with iOS 5 customization has changed. Do you have any code to share about that solution you used in the past? Thank you.

Comment: You are correct. The pieces I was talking about were added in iOS 5 (`popoverBackgroundViewClass`). That leaves you a window or view attached to the top level. I would go with adding a `UIView` to the `[[[view window] rootViewController] view]` and see if that works for you. If not, add it directly to `[view window]`.

Comment: Do I have to try these workarounds directly in my application delegate? For example, could I use them within `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method? If not, where? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use them anywhere you can access the window (or any view within the window). didFinishLaunching is likely a convenient location. You could also do it in your root view controller if you have a special subclass for that.